# RiscV assembler - output is not what I expected for register and immediate operands

Tags: riscv

I am compiling (with RV32I assembler) the following code - with no errors posted on the command line.

```
    slt         x15,x16,x17     # line a
    slt         x15,x16,22      # line b  immediate operand
    slti        x15,x16,22      # line c
    sltu        x15,x16,x17     # line d
    sltu        x15,x16,22      # line e  immediate operand 
    sltiu       x15,x16,22      # line f
```

I notice that the machine code generated for line b is identical to the machine code generated for line c. And I notice the same situation with line e and f - the machine code from these 2 lines are identical. This machine output for these specific instructions, does not meet my expectation. Shouldn't the assembler throw an error or warning that the operands are not technically correct for "slt x15,x16,22" - and the immediate version of this instruction should be used - "slti x15,x16,22"? I invoke the assembler with the '-warn' option.

This result appears to defeat the purpose of having 2 different versions of these instructions. A version where all operands are registers and another version that has registers and one immediate operand.  What if the intention was to use 'x22' instead of '22'?

Comment: What is the exact assembler command line (we need assembler name and version, and also all options used)? What is the `objdump -d`, with hex dump enabled? Assemblers may accept not only real instructions from spec, but also some synthetic mnemonics & operation names, converting it to real opcode which will accept the arguments.

Comment: osgx- I deleted my comments.  I think they were too difficult to read and confusing - after I re-read them I wasn't so sure they were coherent.  Code and commands really need to be formatted and I can't seem to do that in this "Add Comment" utility.

Comment: osgx (continued) -This is a difficult forum to present detailed code and command flow.  When I get time in the next few days - I'll build some details test cases and I am leaning towards posting this issue on GitHub where I think the readability is much improved.  Also - I want to go back and compare RV64 and RV32 assembler outputs as well.  But yes I acknowledge your point - more details are needed here to make progress.  None-the-less, there is definitely some weirdness here with these particular commands.

Comment: DaveW, full code editing is available in question and answer body - with text select and '{}' button on panel (or br, then 4 spaces before every line and br). inline code is marked between "`" chars (backquote, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming). (This is not forum; there is no internet forum on riscv.org, this is just random tag of stackoverflow, and there are not many people in this tag and almost nobody from RISC-V/SiFive)

Comment: osgx - OK this is not a forum - it is more of a private communication between you and me ;) .  I have opened a new issue on GitHub risc/riscv-binutils-gdb  "RiscV assembler - problem with 'SLTI' command".  I am also seeing a problem with the disassembler for SLTI also but I can only post so many problems at a time. cheers!

Comment: osgx - thanks for pointing out the code editing features on Stackoverflow. But I find the time out feature on Add Comment to be annoying.  Guess I could compose in a offline text editor then copy/paste?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, I have moved this issue to GitHub as issue #79 on riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb.

The short answer to my original question is the assembler has a feature  that will convert an instruction like SLTU, regX,regY,imm to the immediate version of the instruction  - SLTIU  regX,regY,imm.  I have not seen any documentation that explains this feature.

By experimenting, here is a list of instructions I have discovered that perform this operation.

```
.text
        slt     x0,x0,-1        # bug 
        sltu    x0,x0,0         # -> sltiu 
        add     x0,x0,5         # -> addi
        xor     x0,x0,8         # -> xori
        or      x0,x0,12        # -> ori
        and     x0,x0,16        # -> andi
        sll     x0,x0,6         # -> slli
        srl     x0,x0,4         # -> srli
        sra     x0,x0,9         # -> srai
```

These instructions assemble with no errors or warnings. And I verified the machine code with the list file output below. (this task is simplified by using the x0 register).

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   fff02013                slt     x0,x0,-1
   4:   00003013                sltiu   x0,x0,0
   8:   00500013                addi    x0,x0,5
   c:   00804013                xori    x0,x0,8
  10:   00c06013                ori     x0,x0,12
  14:   01007013                andi    x0,x0,16
  18:   00601013                slli    x0,x0,0x6
  1c:   00405013                srli    x0,x0,0x4
  20:   40905013                srai    x0,x0,0x9
```

The SLT instruction will write machine code for SLTI but the list file shows SLT - I consider this a bug. For detailed arguments see GitHub #79. All other instructions work as expected.

This approach works only if you have base instruction pairs in the base instructions.  Like ADD/ADDI or XOR/XOI.  But alas, SUB does not have a SUBI instruction in the RiscV ISA. I confirmed this when I received an error trying to assemble SUB with an immediate operand. So if you are the lazy assembler programmer and you don't want to use the correct operands for a base instruction - now you have to remember that should work fine except for SUB. Or add the SUBI instruction to your custom RiscV ISA.

---

What follows are some philosophy comments (so, you can skip the rest of this Answer if your RiscV project is due tomorrow).  First, I feel guilty being critical of any open-source project. I am a long time Linux user and have used many open source tools. Not just for hobby work but for products used by IBM, HP and Dell. I have maybe 6 assemblers I have used in the past - at various levels of expertise. Starting way back with 8080/8085 and I have taught assembly language/computer architecture at the college level. I have to admit there is a lot of expertise that has huddled around RiscV - but none-the-less, I do not consider myself a total noob in assemblers.

**1)**  Assemblers should stay close to the base instructions - and therefore they should present very good reasons when they deviate.  Things like this feature where ADD is internally converted to ADDI inside the assembler -  I feel this feature offers very little value. IMO There may be some value when using disassembly from C/C++ - but I can't put my finger on it. If someone has some details on why this approach was taken please post.

**2)**  RiscV was touted as a fresh new, open ISA.  However, it is similar to MIPS and the problem is MIPS binutils baggage comes with RiscV.  Seems like I have run head-on into the "it worked in MIPS so it has to work in RiscV" thinking on GitHub #79.

**3)** If you don't like the assembly mnemonics - or are too lazy to bother using the correct operands for an instruction - then please consider writing a macro.  For example, you can write a macro for the SUB operation to handle immediate arguments. Resist the urge to carry the macro idea into the assembler - especially if it will not be well documented to new users.  This feature I have discovered, is very similar to a built-in macro in the assembler.

**4)** Bugs in list files are important  - to some people they are critical to the verification task. They should be taken seriously and fixed. I am not certain if the bug on SLT to SLTI for the list file is the fault of the assembler it may be a problem in the binutils objdump utility.

**5)** Pseudoinstructions that are defined in the ISA - are like built-in macros.  I think they should be used sparingly.  Since, I think they can add more confusion.  I write macros for my stack operations like PUSH and POP.  I don't mind writing those macros - I don't feel I need many pseudoinstructions in the assembler or in the ISA.   People who are familiar with gcc/gnu style assembler syntax should be able to quickly code-up some test code using only base instructions and not have to worry about discovering tricks in the assembler.  I stumbled on the SLT trick by accident (typo).

**6)** This trick of converting instructions in the RiscV assembler comes at the expense of 'strong typing' the operands.  If you make a typo (like I did) - but you intended to use all register operands for the base instruction - you will get the immediate form of the instruction with no warnings posted.  So consider this a friendly heads-up. I prefer to invoke the KIS principle in assemblers and lean toward strict enforcement of the correct operands. Or why not offer an assembler option to turn on/off this feature?

7) More and more it seems like assemblers are used mostly for debug and verification and not for general purpose software development.  If you need more abstract code tools - you typically move to C or C++ for embedded cores. Yes you could go crazy writing many assembly macros, but it is much easier to code in C/C++.  You use some inline assembler perhaps to optimize some time critical code - and certainly it helps to disassemble to view compiled C/C++ code. But the C/C++ compilers have improved so much that for many projects this can make assembly optimization obsolete.  Assembly is used for startup code - e.g. if you port Uboot bootloader to another processor you probably will have to deal with some start up files in assembler. So, I think the purpose of assemblers has morphed over time to some startup file duty but the most value in debug and verification.  And that is why I think things like list files have to be correct.  The list of commands that have this feature (e.g. converting from ADD to ADDI based on operand type), mean that the assembly programmer needs to master only one instruction. But RiscV has a small list of base instructions anyway. This is apparent if you had any experience with the old CISC processors. In fact, Risc processors by default should have a small instruction sets. So my question in my original post - why have the immediate version of the instruction? The answer is - for the instructions I have identified - you don't need them. You can code them with either all registers or registers and an immediate value - and the assembler will figure it out. But the HW implementation most definitely needs both versions (register only operands and register and immediate operands).  E.g. the core needs to steer ALU input operands from either the register file output or the immediate value that was stripped from the instruction word.

So, the answer to my original question - "why does this create the exact same machine code?" - is "because that is how the assembler works". But as it stands today - this feature works most of the time..

Comment: The problem with the list file output for SLT/SLTI disassembly was confirmed as a bug.  Progress moved rapidly when I created a test case showing the problem in the operation of 'objcopy' for the list file.  Code has been changed and merged. You can see details at GitHub riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb on the riscv-next branch.  See issue "Fix SLTI disassembly #80".  Once I posted the test case - Andrew and Palmer jumped on this issue very quickly.  I have not built and tested the riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb riscv-next branch so I can't test operation yet.

Comment: An aside - it seems that there is no need for an explicit SUBI instruction, since ADDI is always sign extended.